# TcpListener perform code after accepting a SYN packet in C#

Tags: c#, port, tcplistener

I'm creating a "port honey pot" in C#.
It listens for clients by a TCP server:

```
tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
```

The code keeps on running after a client successfully connects to the server.
However, I also want the server to perform code after accepting a SYN packet.

Is it possible?
Is there any other TCP server implementation that allows it?

Comment: "after 3-way handshake" = "when client successfully connects".

Comment: Yep, but i need to perform code before he successfuly connects. after the first SYN packet.

Comment: No, you don't need it. There is no good reason for a TCP server to do this.

Comment: TCP gives you a nice abstraction away from the details of packets/handshakes/etc. If you want to break that abstraction, you'd have to work at a lower level.

Comment: I need it for creating a honey pot.

Comment: You should also recognise that this would be a good way of opening your server up to DOS attacks - by running *any* code before you've even established that the claimed source address is correct.

Comment: That's a good comment, of course i'll have to handle DOS attacks.
But since it's a honeypot- i'll even wait for them. ;)

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge C# TCP sockets do not give you access to packet descriptors such as SYN. You cannot even open a port in promiscuous mode.

You should open a UDP socket, instead or take a look at libraries like Lidgren.

But then, again, you won't be able to switch from UDP to TCP, so you have one or the other.

Maybe if you explain exactly why and what you need there are other ways.

Comment: Thanks pid!
I accually need them both.
It's for the developement of a honey pot.

Comment: Then Lidgren is your best choice for UDP, you'll get a lot of additional features. I used it for hole punching and SPA (single packet authentication).

Comment: The thing is that i need to simulate a tcp server (not udp).
Isn't there a "low level" implementation of a tcp server that may give this kind of control?